# What does it mean that functional languages provide explicit data structure representations?

Tags: functional-programming

I'm read chapter 1.13 [AN INTRODUCTION TO FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING THROUGH LAMBDA CALCULUS](https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/gjm.lambook88.pdf) and see it. What is the "explicit data structure representations" that is usually absent in imperative languages? Could anybody give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anybody give an example please?

This is just an example of implicit structure, Array, compared to explicit structure, Linked List.

The programs below could be written in countless ways. Neither example is particularly amazing. Each example is just meant to show code you could expect to see in the wild.

---

**Overview**

An **Array** is a *non*-explicit, nebulous bucket of `index`->`value` mappings.  It requires the use of an arbitrary index input to read a value. You can "iterate" thru it by using a counter, but really the counter has no relation to the array itself – you're still just performing random lookups using an arbitrary index – it doesn't matter if those happen to be in "sequence" or not.

[image]

---

A [**Linked List**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is an *explicitly* structured data container. It has a defined beginning, end, and meaningful way to programmatically interact with the structure. Processing the list starts with `car` and proceeds using `cdr` until the *null* terminator is found. It also has explicit ways to create new pairs (`cons`).

[image]

---

**Non-explicit code example**

Here we have an imperative-style program written in JavaScript. There is arguably no structure to this program.

- `xs` is a globally-defined array that is essentially a large blob of assignments – *values* linked to *indices*
- `doSomething` changes an assignment based on the provided index – it does so *implicitly* on `xs`
- `main` also has *implicit* knowledge of `xs` – or at least, it has implicit knowledge that `doSomething` operates on `xs`
- also notice that because `doSomething` only sets a new assignment of a known index, it *mutates* the original input
- `main` has no explicit output; it *implicitly* relies upon `doSomething` to change the underlying data, `xs`

```js
function doSomething (i) {
  xs[i] = 'changed'
}

function main () {
  doSomething(1)
  doSomething(2)
}

let xs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

console.log(xs)       // [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

console.log(main())   // undefined

console.log(xs)       // [ 'a', 'changed', 'changed', 'd', 'e' ]
```

---

**Explicit code example**

Here is a functional-style program written in Racket.

- `xs` is still globally-defined but it is in a known, *explicit* structure – a [*Linked List*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)
- `doSomething` can no longer reference an index directly to *reassign* a value. Instead, it requires both an index input and an *explicitly structured* list input – only then can recursively build a *new* list with the *new* value in the appropriate position.
- `main` can no longer maintain ignorance of the data it operates on – `xs` is *explicitly* and purposefully threaded thru successive `doSomething` calls, using the return value of each, and ultimately returning the final result

```scm
#lang racket

(define (do-something i xs)
  (if (zero? i)
      (cons "changed" xs)
      (cons (car xs) (do-something (sub1 i) (cdr xs)))))

(define (main xs)
  (do-something 2 (do-something 1 xs)))

(define xs '(a b c d e))

(println xs)         ;; => '(a b c d e)

(println (main xs))  ;; => '(a "changed" "changed" d e)

(println xs)         ;; => '(a b c d e)
```